# I cant send with Enter

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea, sendmessage

Send with button works, but press enter he make a new row. I need to send with enter. Any suggestion? :)

```
 echo "</div>\n";
 echo "<div style='float: right; width: 10%;'>";
 echo "<input type='submit' name='send' id='send' value='&nbsp;' onclick="$('#loading').fadeIn(); sAjaxObj = 'profile-msgs'; sAjaxUrl = ''; \$.post('/ajax.php?act=message_save&ts=' + Number(new Date()), \$('#form-message').serializeArray(), fnAjaxEvaluateReload);" class='button-ok' />&nbsp;";

 echo "</div>\n";
 echo "<div style='clear: both;'></div>\n";
 echo "</form>\n";
 }
 }
```

Thnaks guys

Comment: Send what with enter? If you're talking about the textarea, you should probably use a regular input instead.

Comment: oh sry is a text-area. And regural input doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this between your existing script tags:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_message').keyup(function(e) {
        var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
            $('#send').click();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Note that this is jQuery code and you will need to have the jQuery library loaded -- but your existing code is also jQuery, so you probably have done that already.

Comment: Thanks man it works! Now press enter I send the massage. But if i repeat this, then nothing. But is still awesome. Can you help me with this too?

Comment: I'm swamped at the moment... Best bet is to open a new question -- someone will probably beat me to it and you won't have to wait. Feel free to open as many related questions as you wish, as long as they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

To send on "enter" you would need to not allow the creation of new lines in the textarea (as you cannot know whether the user wants a new line or to submit when they press enter, computers aren't psychic).

If you need new lines in the textarea, then you cannot do "submit on enter".

If you do not need new lines, then change it to a `<input type="text" />`